# Proof of a basic isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How do you prove that $D_2 \cong V \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$? Where $V$ is the Klein-4 Group and $D_2$ is the dihedral group with cardinality 4.

We have that $D_2 := \{1,r,s,sr \}$ and $V := \{ 1, \sigma, \tau, \gamma \}$ .
What isomorphism should be constructed between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prahlad touched on my favorite method towards the end because it's so elementary.  Here's how I'd do this:  Let $G$ be a group such that $|G| = 4$.  Now, suppose $G$ is not cyclic.  That is, there exists no element of order $4$.  Therefore, all non-identity elements have order $2$ by Lagrange's theorem.  From here, we can construct a multiplication table using the rule that $g^2 = e$ for all $g \in G$.  We construct this table with the Sodoku rule in mind.  That is, every element of the group will appear exactly once in each row and in each column.  You will quickly find that a single multiplication table is forced, and none other can exist.

We conclude that all non-cyclic groups of order $4$ must fall into a single isomorphism class.

Comment: Great answer, clear and concise.

Answer (score 1):

An isomorphism must map $1$ to $1$ and must map elements of order 2 to elements of order 2. So start with $f(1) = 1$ and $f(r) = \sigma$. Now assuming $\gamma = \tau\sigma$ in $V$, you may choose $f(s) = \tau$ and $f(sr) = \gamma$.

Now check that all products are mapped correctly. In this case, it is perhaps easiest to write out the multiplication table for both groups and then map the elements term by term.

Comment: In general, what is the best way to construct an isomorphism for groups of small cardinality?

Comment: Perhaps the multiplication table - but this can get cumbersome quickly. Another is to "guess" a surjective homomorphism, and check that its kernel is trivial.